# My code supposed to get the available ports but it didn't

Tags: c#, serial-port

This code

```
void getPorts()
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);
        }
```

Should fill `comboBox1` with the available ports but it do nothing, i googled about the code and i found that the same code works for many people but it don't for me, why?

I used a debugger to figure out the values of the variables and the result was that the `ports` array still empty after using `SerialPort.GetPortNames()`

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 .NET Framework 4

Comment: Use a debugger check the value of `ports` actually has values in it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain its empty

Comment: there ya go, you have no serial ports :)